# Alternative to the Gram-Schmidt Procedure for Orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I was wondering if there is an alternative to the Gram-Schmidt procedure, which instead of being a successive *orthogonalization* scheme, would be non-successive (simultaneous)? In other words, is there a scheme in which the order of the vectors doesn't matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? There is always some ordering (implicit or explicit).

Comment: What I mean is that if we take the resulting orthogonal set from the the Gram-Schmidt procedure, and use those vectors as explanatory variables in a regression, the first chosen vector in the orthogonalization process would have the most effect, followed by the second-chosen one, etc. Would there be an orthogonalization scheme that would go around this issue?

Comment: You might consider trying the (truncated) SVD.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how is SVD different from Principal Component Analysis? Since PCA has the same artifact of allocating more effect to the first factor, then the second, ..., SVD could result in something similar. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, SVD can be used for PCA. It is hard, however, to help further since it is not clear to me what *precisely* does "most effect" mean.

Comment: According to the gram-schmidt process, the later an explanatory variable is indexed among the other variables, the smaller its residual vector is because preceding variables' residual vectors are subtracted from it. As a result, the explanatory variable's regression coefficient is also smaller. This seems to be an artifact of PCA as well. Would it be the case for SVD?

Comment: Quoting from Wikipedia about Gram Schmidt: "Other orthogonalization algorithms use Householder transformations or Givens rotations. The algorithms using Householder transformations are more stable than the stabilized Gram–Schmidt process. On the other hand, the Gram–Schmidt process produces the jth orthogonalized vector after the jth iteration, while orthogonalization using Householder reflections produces all the vectors only at the end."

So maybe Givens rotation might be what you are looking for?